# How to install virtualenv by using pip in MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, virtualenv, macos-sierra, tensorflow

Command which i used to install virtualenv:-

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Result:-

```
The directory '/Users/apple/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/Users/apple/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to install tensorflow on my mac but on very first step `sudo pip install virtualenv` it shows the above error.!!

Comment: I re-edited the question again please see it.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `virtualenv` is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -H pip install virtualenv
```

(kodlan didn't literally mean `foo`...)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get rid of this error when trying to run pip just add -H flag:

```
sudo -H pip install foo
```

Comment: `sudo -H pip install foo`

Collecting foo
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement foo (from versions: )No matching distribution found for foo