# How do i install TensorFlow in MacOS 10.13 High Sierra?

Tags: macos, machine-learning, tensorflow, virtualenv, macos-sierra

I tried below command but it doesn't worked.!!

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `virtualenv: command not found` tells you exactly what is wrong. You need to install virtualenv to use it. Once you install it the command above should work. Then you will need to activate your virtual environment and use pip to install tensorflow.

Comment: Please see my this question too on installing `virualenv`
[How to install virtualenv by using pip in MacOS High Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552127/how-to-install-virtualenv-by-using-pip-in-macos-high-sierra/46564033#46564033)

Comment: Not sure about your other question. The native python install on OS X is weird, I would suggest installing python via Homebrew.

Comment: Should i have to reinstall python using Homebrew, this is what you are suggesting me?? @madwombat

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. You asked about a problem installing tensorflow and I explained what is going on. Technically, you don't even have to install virtualenv to install tensorflow, it is just considered a good practice to have everything you do in a virtaul environment. Personally, I don't use pre-installed python on OS X because it is outdated and because it is installed in system locations where it requires root access to install things. I use python 3.6 that I have installed via Homebrew. You can also install latest python 2.7 via Homebrew. And it might solve some of your problems.

Comment: so do you know how to install tensorflow without installing virtualenv???
Isit possible?? @madwombat

Comment: `pip install tensorflow` should do

Comment: And do you know how to use it? @madwombat

Comment: How to use tensorflow?